# How do I print json code with just a separate value in it?

Tags: php, json

I'm currently trying to print json code but I'm facing this issue.. Not able to print. This is my json code while trying to print in php..

```
{  
 "success":1,
 "results":[  
  {  
     "id":"580395",
     "sport_id":"1",
     "time":"1515232810",
     "time_status":"1",
     "league":{  
        "id":"891",
        "name":"Israel Youth League",
        "cc":"il"
     },
     "home":{  
        "id":"10116",
        "name":"Maccabi Tel Aviv U19",
        "image_id":"222408",
        "cc":"il"
     },
     "away":{  
        "id":"46743",
        "name":"Maccabi Petach Tikva U19",
        "image_id":"240834",
        "cc":"il"
     },
     "ss":"2-1",
     "timer":{  
        "tm":95,
        "ts":26,
        "tt":"1",
        "ta":4
     },
     "scores":{  
        "2":{  
           "home":"2",
           "away":"1"
        },
        "1":{  
           "home":"2",
           "away":"0"
        }
     },
     "stats":{  
        "attacks":[  
           "39",
           "31"
        ],
        "corners":[  
           "8",
           "2"
        ],
        "corner_h":[  
           "5",
           "0"
        ],
        "dangerous_attacks":[  
           "28",
           "22"
        ],
```

This is how I tried to get the CORNERS..

```
<?php $obj = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($obj['results'] as $result){?>

<?php echo $result['corners'];?>
<?php } ?>
```

I don't get any output.. There will be two output here 1> home team corners total count 2> away team corners total count..

Someone help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems you never searched for a solution to your problem. Your question has been answered hundreds of times.

Comment: Why are you closing the PHP tag?

Comment: @Akintunde007 I have gone through to many previous questions but it doesn't solve my problem.. Please share link if you sure similar question has been solved before..

Comment: @JayGupta What is output you are expecting, can you paste output here

Comment: `corners` key is under `stats` key, you should __learn__ how to work with multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @whoami It will be something like Home team corner : 2 | Away team corner : 8

Comment: @JayGupta Your json data was in valid

Comment: @whoami which data is invalid?

Answer (score 2):

```
        <?php 
            $obj = json_decode($data, true);
            foreach($obj['results']['corners'] as $result){
                        echo $result;
        } 
        ?>
```